# How to set minimum height to the 100% of the viewing screen and half of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have single page site where 1st part main part which should be 100% of the viewers screen/browser size and the 2nd part should be below the viewing area, so when a user clicks on a link , the page gets scrolled down to the second part .

how do i achieve this.,
i have tried this so far, but its not setting min-height yo 100%

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="firsthalf">
this is the first part of the site
<a href="#help"> <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg"></i>
<div class="notice">this is aligned to bottom of first half
</div></div>   
</div>    

<div class="container">
<div id="help" class="secondhalf">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<div class="well">
we are in second part of the site
</div>
<a href="#top" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up "></i> Top</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.firsthalf{
height:100%;
}
.notice{
margin-bottom:0%;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
.secondhalf{
margin-top:25%;
margin-bottom:50%;
padding-top:25px;
min-height:50%;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4yk2q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play with `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;`... they are your friend in this case...

[**Solution demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yk2q/1/)

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    height:100%;   /* first make container full height */
}
.firsthalf {
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position: relative; /* make parent div relative */
}
.notice {
   padding-bottom:5px;
   position: absolute; /* this does the base line trick */
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks , this is best, i was thinking about setting display:table

Comment: `display:table` is good but every css is good in certain markup layouts only...`position` is best suited and more cleaner in your case!! :)

Comment: thanks , it tells me to wait 2 minutes, to accept answer, i guess icant accept answer instantly after creating question.,

Comment: lol...u got ur answer within 2 minutes of u posting question...wish i might be that lucky....happy new year mate!! :D

Comment: happy new year to you 2 :) why the lower box not in the same width and notice  txt cant be centered  ? any idea ? http://jsfiddle.net/4yk2q/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44694/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-amb)

Answer (score 1):

viewport height (vh)
You are looking for height:50vh; or height: 100vh;

There are a few options you may find useful:

vh (viewport height)
vw (viewport width)
vmin (viewport minimum length)
vmax (viewport maximum length)

http://stanhub.com/how-to-make-div-element-100-height-of-browser-window-using-css-only/

```
.secondhalf{
margin-top:25%;
margin-bottom:50%;
padding-top:25px;
height:50vh;

}
```

Edit:  make sure it is supported by the browsers you need to support.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units